# Print report directly to the printer

Tags: vb.net, ssrs-2008, reporting-services

How can I print report directly to the printer, instead of viewing it on screen?

Thanks / Furqan

Answer (score 1):

You may need to use the web service to call the report, receive the byte stream and print directly.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152787.aspx