# JasperReports: Print a report directly at client side printer

Tags: java, javascript, jasper-reports

I am using *JasperReports* for generating the reports.

My requirement is to print a report directly at client side printer.

I tried *`JasperPrintManager.printReport(JP_Print, false)`* method for printing the report but report going to the Server side printer.

Is there any way to do this using *JavaScript* or *Java*?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JasperPrintManager.printReport(jasperPrint,true)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1752706/jasperprintmanager-printreportjasperprint-true)

Comment: See also: [Print JasperReports client-side?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4694737/876298) & [How to generate/print reports on the client side](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4691441/876298) & [Printing JasperReport From Applet](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5116474/876298). Did you try to search on *SO*?

Comment: I have searched in SO but the solutions are not there in java

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5093451/print-report-directly-to-the-printer

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/643080/print-without-printer-selection-dialog

Comment: Why do you want to print the report directly? Why not export it as a PDF and let the user print it themselves?